# Looking for an Alternative, Satirical Lord of the Rings Essay

Tags: story-identification, the-lord-of-the-rings

Years ago I stumbled upon a satirical essay online all about Middle-earth and the War of the Ring.

I can't remember the details but the overall idea of it was that the Orcs and Sauron had been oppressed by the forces of Gondor, Gandalf and the Hobbits. It was a long essay but general ideas.

Hobbits were manipulating the whole of Middle-earth in order to allow them to maintain the supply of Pipe Weed as required.

Gondor's economy was based entirely on the war effort against Mordor and so they perpetuated the war against Sauron and the Orcs.

Orcs and Sauron simply wanted to be able to walk around in the sun without the fear of an arrow or sword killing them.

There was a lot more and it was a very very funny read.

Has anyone else read this, or can they point me towards where it might be online please? I will say it was not the book *Bored of the Rings* (Which I have)

Comment: Could it be [The Last Ringbearer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Ringbearer)? That was a book, not an essay, although the English translation is only published online.

Comment: No, wasn't that, it was alot more of a satirical version but never read the last RingBearer before so will be reading the ebook when I have some spare time :).

Comment: Could I ask what format this essay was in? Was it a book i.e.paperback ?

Comment: I First came across it online back in the days of Usenet Groups being popular. I then came across it a second time on a Lord of the Rings Fan Site about 7-8 years ago and downloaded and saved it but the PC I had it on died long ago and have never been able to find it since.

Comment: Definitely not what you are looking for, but checkout "Lord of the Ping" on userfriendly.org

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-chat/1316165/posts) it's a fictional interview which brings up the points mentioned here. However, since the questioner mentioned an essay format perhaps this isn't the glove that fits...

But, it's of a decent length and old enough that it could be what he is referring to so I'm treating it as an answer.

Here are some specific quotes that address the points raised

> The thing to remember is that the crop they [The Hobbits] are tilling is, in fact, pipe-weed, an addictive drug transported and sold throughout Middle Earth for great profit
>
> The Orcs have no resources. They're desperate.
>
> The military-industrial-complex that exists in Gondor. This constant state of alertness. This constant state of fear.